# Eqiuvalence class of Riemann integrable functions under the almost everywhere equal relation

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $ f : [a, b] \to\Bbb R $ be an arbitrary Riemann integrable function. Then is it true that there always exists a continuous function $ g : [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ such that g and f  are almost everywhere equal. If  it is true than how to prove and if not than can we find a counter example.

I know that there exists bounded Lebesgue integrable function  $f : [a, b] \to\Bbb R$ which is not almost everywhere equal to any Riemann integrable function , e.g the characteristic function of fat cantor set. So the question that comes to my mind is that whether there exists a Riemann integrable function $ f : [a, b] \to\Bbb R$ which is not almost everywhere equal to any continuous function.

Also conversely if $ f : [a, b] \to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function then is it true that there always exists a non continuous Riemann integrable function $g : [a, b] \to\Bbb R$ such that $g$ and  $f$ are almost everywhere equal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The converse you mention in your final paragraph is trivially true: just modify $f$ at a single (or finitely many) point to make it discontinuous

Comment: Take $f=\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1]}$ then it's Riemann integrable on $[-1,2]$, but there are no continuous function $g:[-1,2]\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f=g$ a.e.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. It is Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$ and not almost everywhere equal to any continuous function.